# SSRS won't let me edit a report's properties

Tags: reporting-services

I have a similar SSRS installation running on 2 computers (using MS SQL server 2012 express). On one of them I am unable to change a report's properties. hovering over the arrow I get the tip "open menu"
here is a screenshot of the "good" server:
[image: SSRS - good]

but on the other server the down-arrow is not filled (see pic), and I can't access the properties menu. Hovering over the arrow I see the tip "Items in Home":
[image: SSRS - bad]

both computers are running with a similar security settings. The good one is a Win2k8 x86 with IE8. The bad one is a win7 x64 with IE 10. I tries changing the browser on the bad computer to chrome and got the exact same results.

I have a feeling that re-installing SSRS will not help me in this case. I will try that as a last resort.

It would really help me to hear if anyone has had a similar experience with SSRS? Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you tried running IE as an Administrator? That does seem to affect some RS behaviour.

Comment: You're seeing the "Site Settings" option in both cases, so it certainly looks like you're admin both places.  Hmmm.

Comment: @paul IE is running as admin and from the user that installed SSRS in both cases.

Comment: Try compatibility mode

Comment: @paul THANKS! U R the man! Compatibility mode solved the problem. you saved me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the compatibility mode in mode there is a simpler way to achieve this.

In the SRSS page hit *F12*, then change the compatibility mode to *Internet Explorer 9*.

It will work like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

just to quote Paul: "Try compatibility mode"...
seems like there is an issue when installing SSRS2012 on a Win7 x64 causing the arrow not to functions (and also chrome shows the same problem).
solution was running IE in compatibility mode. seems odd (and a little disappointing) that MS didn't test this scenario before releasing.

in any case, if you run into this -- "Try compatibility mode".

Answer (score 2):

Your permissions are probably different for the two, either at the root installation or the level of the items.

Three levels of permission to consider:

1. Who installed the SSRS installation and is it the default instance?  That user at first is the ONLY ADMIN and as such has admin rights to change things.  As such they can access 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager' under All Programs>SQL Server (Version)>Config Tools.  This is the main admin tool of SSRS hosting.  If you can't get here you can't do anything later.
2. When you hit the landing page and go to 'Site Settings' in the upper right and then security what users are there?  Generally Local Admin or similar is 'Administrator' and there may sometimes by a user.  You can set your user as an admin if you have rights.  If not use the local admin account.
3. When you are at the landing page click 'Folder Settings' and then Security.  'Content Manager' is the highest level which allows you to do everything.  Set your user as this role.

If you can't do 2 or 3, you don't have enough rights.  You need to go to 'Reporting Services Configuration Manager from step 1 with that account.  Go to the landing page with that user and add more users.  If you want them to be able to CHANGE things you need to ensure they are higher than just 'browser'.

SSRS by default does not allow users to have admin priveledges until an admin adds them to those roles.